# What's the best way to go about stylizing a Sencha Touch app?

Tags: css, mobile, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sass

I'm a newbie, and I designed an App with jQuery Mobile, but those in power told me that I should redo it using Sencha Touch.  I'm having a little difficulty understanding Sencha Touch.  Should I just use my developer tools and change their large CSS file?  Should I add html and classes to each .js page `cls: 'whatev',` and than add my css.  Should I mess with the SCSS file?

I understand that my question is an amateurish one, but I would really appreciate any direction before I begin.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a theming guide that covers a lot of the basics: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/theming

Comment: That is incredibly helpful.  I don't know y i had such a hard time coming across it.  Thanks Evan.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to refer this very informative post: http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch